# SSLEngine does not decrypt all the data

Tags: rest, http, ssl, encryption, sslengine

I am trying to use SSLengine with SocketChannels in non-blocking mode.

The handshake is done correctly but when i try to read & decrypt http posts from channelsocket, only the headers are decrypted and the body disapear:

```
<code>
int num=0;

            while(num==0){
                num=socketChannel.read(peerNetData);
                if(num==-1)
                    break;
            }

            if (num == -1) {
                System.out.println("channel closed");
            } else if (num == 0) {
                System.out.println("no bytes to read");
            } else {
                // Process incoming data

                peerNetData.flip();

                SSLEngineResult res = engine.unwrap(peerNetData, peerAppData);
               //return a ok status 

peerNetData.flip();
            peerAppData.flip();
            System.out.println(new String(peerNetData.array()));  
            System.out.println(new String(peerAppData.array()));  


</code>
```

when printing the encrypted data in peerNetData i am getting :

?>.//POST test HTTP/1.1
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 20
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Host: 192.168.X.X

?>.//?>.//?>.//?>.//?>.//?>.//?>.//?>.//?>.//?>.//?>.//   <--- encrypted chars here

but when i print the decrypted data in peerAppData i am getting

POST test HTTP/1.1/
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 20
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Host: 192.168.X.X
// and then three empty lines here.

is this a decryption problem with SSlengine??

Thanks

Also i would like to add that unwrap method return an OK status.

Comment: `while(num==0)` ? Sorry, but what's wrong with all the other numbers out there?

Comment: while(num==0) guarrante me that the loop while be exited if and only if socket have received something. ( in my case the socket is able to read all together since the message is small)

Comment: Yes, but is there a guarantee that it will read *all* data?

Comment: in general cases of course we have to handle the underflow case. But in my case all the data is being read and the SSLengine return an Ok status.

Comment: OK, in that case I'll reinstate my answer, but beware that I haven't had much experience with the particular channel and SSLEngine classes. Basically it is a description what could happen within the SSL layer. Note that it would be interesting to know the ciphersuite in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could well be that the actual POST content was empty except for the 2 empty lines (one line is standard after the header, if I'm not mistaken). Because of [PKCS#7 padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29), at least 16 bytes of data (one block, 16 bytes for AES) will be encrypted at the minimum.

Besides that the data will also contain a [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) as SSL usually uses MAC-then-encrypt (also known as the wrong way around [according to most](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac)).

So it may look like there is data, even if it is just overhead.